# Electron basic auth pop up not working

Tags: electron

I am trying to open my node website inside electron app using its url, the node app has basic auth. The basic auth popup in electron app doesn't seem to work, any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543664/how-to-enable-a-pop-up-for-authentication-for-electron

Answer (score 4):

What doesn't work? By default Electron will cancel all authentications, so you need to add a listener for the [`login` event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.2.8/docs/api/app.md#event-login) to override the default behavior. Something like this:

```
app.on('login', (event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // popup a dialog to let the user enter a username/password
  // ...
  callback(username, password);
});
```