# How to enable a pop up for authentication for electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am creating an electron app that accesses a url. And when navigated to the URL the user clicks on a button and are redirected to a URL that displays this pop up in Chrome.

How can I enable/show this popup in electron? It doesn't seem to enable it by default.

[image]

Comment: I believe you should receive ['login' event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-login) for this case, which you can handle

Comment: @pergy That is exactly what I needed thanks. If you post it as an answer I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see on the picture is that Chrome opens a popup for handle authentication event.

However, Electron doesn't make such popup by default, as it stated in the documentation of [`'login'` event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#event-login)

> The default behavior is to cancel all authentications, to override this you should prevent the default behavior with `event.preventDefault()` and call `callback(username, password)` with the credentials.

This means, you should handle [`'login'` event of your webContents](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-login) manually and open a popup window by yourself or do whatever you want.