# Electron browserWindow password prompt

Tags: electron

I have a simple electron app that wraps around a web app. The web app prompts for user name but electron doesn't show the prompt and directly goes to the 401 Authorization Required page. Is there a setting I need to change to make the prompt show? I can't seem to find it in the documentation. Any help is appreciated.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

function createWindow() {
    browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    browserWindow.loadURL('https://domain')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable a pop up for authentication for electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543664/how-to-enable-a-pop-up-for-authentication-for-electron)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to this ["login" event](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-login).

Create your own prompt. For example, create a browser window which loads an HTML form and when the user fills the username and password fields pass the credentials back via [ipc calls](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages) to the callback.

```js
app.on("login", (event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  createAuthPrompt().then(credentials => {
    callback(credentials.username, credentials.password);
  });
});

function createAuthPrompt() {
  const authPromptWin = new BrowserWindow();
  authPromptWin.loadFile("auth-form.html"); // load your html form

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ipcMain.once("form-submission", (event, username, password) => {
      authPromptWin.close();
      const credentials = {
        username,
        password
      };
      resolve(credentials);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: how do i pass the login info from ipcMain.on('form-submission') to the callback?

Comment: Check my updated answer for an example on one way you can possibly do this.

Comment: i did something similar, i'm facing another problem now, can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697133/electron-callback-can-only-be-called-for-once